# How to reflect on a ActiveRecord scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, reflection, rails-activerecord

I would like to discover at runtime the number of parameters a query scope should receive.

I tryed the following:

```
class Test < ActiveRecord::Base
    scope :my_scope, Proc.new{ |q, x|
      where("attr = ? and attrb = ?", q, x)
    }

    def self.my_scope_args
      self.method(:my_scope).parameters
    end
end
```

But calling

```
Test.my_scope_args
```

returns [[:rest, :args]]. If I reflect directly on the Proc object I get the desired result:

```
Proc.new{ |q, x|
    where("attr = ? and attrb = ?", q, x)
}.parameters
```

returns  [[:opt, :q], [:opt, :x]]

There is a way I can get a reference to the scope's underlying Proc object so I can reflect on it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the fine [Active Record Query Interface Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#passing-in-arguments):

> **14.1 Passing in arguments**
>   [...]
>   Using a class method is the preferred way to accept arguments for scopes. These methods will still be accessible on the association objects.

So instead of this:

```
scope :my_scope, Proc.new{ |q, x|
  where("attr = ? and attrb = ?", q, x)
}
```

you should be saying this:

```
def self.my_scope(q, x)
  where(:attr => q, :attrb => x)
end
```

Then your `my_scope_args` will work as expected.

Comment: the problem is when you want to chain them.

Comment: or maybe try to do the same thing scopes do `def my_scope(x); all.scoping { "scope code goes here" }; end`

Comment: @IsmaelAbreu: What chaining problem would that be? You can `M.scope1(x).scope2(y)` just fine when `scope1` and `scope2` are class methods.

Comment: I guess there are only minor problems with it. I saw on a blog post by Carlos Antônio. But I guess it's fine to use it if the OP really needs to know the arguments.

Comment: here is the blog post http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2013/02/active-record-scopes-vs-class-methods/

Comment: @IsmaelAbreu: Sorry, I don't see anything interesting in that blog post, perhaps you could explain what your problem with using the recommended scopes-with-arguments technique is. I still don't know what "the problem is when you want to chain them" means in this context.

Comment: Tanks for the answer @muistooshort I guess the post just advise we should concert about the nullity of the arguments if we are using class methods. So we don't end up with this when chaining queries: Post.by_status('').recent
NoMethodError: undefined method `recent' for nil:NilClass

Answer (score 2):

It does seem you can't access the proc for the scope. And you get the params args because it's defined like so in

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/e5ef3abdd2336c34cd853a1f845f79b8b19fbb1b/activerecord/lib/active_record/scoping/named.rb#L161